# using xsl:number with xsl:key to get node position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to figure out how to get the multi position (1.1) of node when assigned to keys. Below is a stripped down reproduction of the issue:

**Input XML:**

```
<doc>
    <chapter>
        <title>Chapter</title>
        <section>
            <para0>
                <title>section</title>
            </para0>
        </section>
        <section>
            <para0>
                <title>section</title>
            </para0>
        </section>
        <procedure>
            <title>procedure</title>
        </procedure>
        <section>
            <para0>
                <title>section</title>
            </para0>
        </section>
        <section>
            <para0>
                <title>section</title>
            </para0>
        </section>
        <procedure>
            <title>procedure</title>
        </procedure>
    </chapter>
</doc>
```

**Desired output**

```
<output>
    <chapter>Chapter 1
        <section>section 1.1</section>
        <section>section 1.2</section>
        <section>procedure 1.3</section>
        <section>section 1.4</section>
        <section>section 1.5</section>
        <section>procedure 1.6</section>
    </chapter>
</output>
```

**current output**

```
<output>
    <chapter>Chapter 1
        <section>section 1</section>
        <section>section 1</section>
        <section>procedure 1</section>
        <section>section 1</section>
        <section>section 1</section>
        <section>procedure 1</section>
    </chapter>
</output>
```

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="numbering" match="chapter/procedure" use="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:key name="numbering" match="chapter/section/para0" use="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <chapter>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="multiple" count="chapter" format="1"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="section/para0 | procedure ">
                <section>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:number level="any" select="key('numbering', generate-id())/title" from="chapter" format="1.1"/>
                </section>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </chapter>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Saxon 9.5 the following stylesheet produces the output you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <chapter>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="multiple" count="chapter" format="1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </chapter>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section | procedure ">
        <section>
            <xsl:value-of select="(title, para0/title)[1]"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number level="multiple" count="chapter | section | procedure" format="1.1"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```